# DeepStreaming on digitalocean

Tags: stream, digital-ocean

I'm working on setting up deepstearm.io using [this guide](https://deepstreamhub.com/open-source/integrations/other-digital-ocean/#step-2-configure-redis).

However, I get the following error:

> PLUGIN_ERROR | storage wasn't initialised in time

Able to ping mongodb serever from deepstream server

I tried changing `dependencyInitialisationTimeout` to `20000`. It didn't work.

I Attached the command and error message for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a firewall rule on the mongodb node allowing incoming connections to port 27017

```
ufw allow  27017
```

Maybe it is even better to just allow the deepstream node ip